# Cocos2D bottom right anchor point

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I want to make a label's anchor point to the bottom right so it can view different values without going off screen (the label is on the bottom right corner of the screen). I tried `highscoreLabel.anchorPoint = ccp(highscoreLabel.contentSize.width, 0);`

But that didn't seem to work.

Comment: I actually figured it out. Seems like i misunderstood anchorpoint a bit. The solution is: highscoreLabel.anchorPoint = ccp(1, 0);

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found it out. Seems like i misunderstood anchorpoint a bit. The solution is:

```
highscoreLabel.anchorPoint = ccp(1, 0);
```